# Parse HTML with Nokogiri and get text with the closest "<div>"

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I have HTML containing:

```
<div class = "s">
   <p> text1 </p>
   <div class = "i">
      <p> text2 </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

I need get all text with the closest `<div>` with class `"s"`.

For example, I'm trying to get:

```
array = []
html.css("s").each do |element|
  array << element.text.strip
end
```

It is all good except that in my array appears `"text2"`, and I don't want those. So for `"text2"`, the closest `<div>` had class `"i"`, and I don't want see it in my array.

How can I resolve this? There can be different class names, and deeper nesting, for example:

```
<div class = "s">
   <p> text1 </p>
   <div class = "i">
      <p> text2 </p>
      <div class = "s">
         <p> text3 </p>
         <div class = "p">
           <p> text4 </p>
         </div>
      </div> 
   </div>
</div>
```

from this, I want to get an array with: `["text1", "text3"]`

Comment: If things are nested, the results will be nested too. What about writing a better selector that targets the `<p>` within the right `<div>`, for example: `.s + p`

Comment: @tadman there is can texts without <p> for example =(

Comment: An example of the sorts of edge cases you're working with would help.

Comment: It's really important that you supply accurate examples of the HTML you're trying to parse. Don't make us play 20 questions with you to learn what the real problem is, provide a minimal example that covers the issues. That helps us help you.

Comment: So you want the first non-blank text node contained in the `div`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a better XPath-only answer. My original answer is below.

```
# Given a Nokogiri::HTML document in the `html` variable:
html.xpath("//text()[normalize-space() and ancestor::div[1][@class='s']]").map(&:text).map(&:strip)
```

This just finds all non-blank text nodes whose nearest `div` ancestor has a class of `s`. It's the same thing as my original answer, except it's entirely done in XPath.

```
<div class = "s">
   <p> text1 </p>
   <div class = "i">
      <p> text2 </p>
   </div>
</div>
# => ["text1"]

<div class = "s">
   <p> text1 </p>
   <div class = "i">
      <p> text2 </p>
      <div class = "s">
         <p> text3 </p>
         <div class = "p">
           <p> text4 </p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
# => ["text1", "text3"]

<div class = "s">
  <div class='p'>
    text 1
  </div>
  text 2
</div>
# => ["text 2"]
```

---

Original answer:

```
html.search("//div[@class='s']//text()").
  select {|t| t.ancestors("div").first.attr("class") == "s" }.
  map(&:text).join.squeeze.strip
# => "text1"
```

The basic idea here is that we find all text nodes which descend from `div.s` then find the nearest `div` ancestor for each text node, and only accept the nodes which have a nearest div ancestor with a class of `s`.

It's a bit CPU-intensive, but it fulfills the strict requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
html.css('.s > p').map {|node| node.text.strip }
```

Comment: and if text without <p> or another tag? =(

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT, &:noblanks)
<div class = "s">
   <p> text1 </p>
   <div class = "i">
      <p> text2 </p>
      <div class = "s">
         <p> text3 </p>
         <div class = "p">
           <p> text4 </p>
         </div>
      </div> 
   </div>
</div> 
EOT

doc.search('.s').map{ |div| div.child.text.strip } 
# => ["text1", "text3"]
```

I think what makes it difficult to find the appropriate nodes, the `child` of the `".s"` nodes, is the next Text node containing the "\n" due to the HTML formatting. Ignoring them is difficult because they might not be text, they might be a node you want returned.

The trick is to tell Nokogiri to strip out blank nodes as it parses the document, which effectively would flatten the HTML, removing all indentation, making it possible to trust that the next node after a target is one that is wanted.

---

> foobar would cause this technique to fail.

Yep, it would, and would require additional logic to weed those out:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT, &:noblanks)
<div class = "s">
   <p> text1 </p>
   <div class = "i">
      <p> text2 </p>
      <div class = "s">
         <p> text3 </p>
         <div class = "p">
           <p> text4 </p>
         </div>
      </div> 
      <div class='s'><div class='i'>foobar</div></div>
   </div>
</div> 
EOT
```

Here's the old logic:

```
doc.search('.s').map{ |div| div.child.text.strip } 
# => ["text1", "text3", "foobar"]
```

And a quick test to weed out the unwanted:

```
doc.search('.s').reject{ |div| div.child['class'] == 'i' }.map{ |div| div.child.text.strip } 
# => ["text1", "text3"]
```

Comment: `<div class='s'><div class='i'>foobar</div></div>` would cause this technique to fail.